# Motion of Frictionless Particle Sliding Along a Helix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Suppose a frictionless particle $P$ is sliding down the helix
$$
r(t) = a\cos(\theta)i + a\sin(\theta)j+b\theta k
$$
with the initial position $(a,0,0)$. The law of conservation of energy tells us that the particle's speed is $\sqrt{2gz}$ when the particle has fallen down a distance $z$.

I want to represent $\theta$ as a function of $t$.

My attempt is as following: first, speed of the particle is
$$
\|r'(t)\| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}|\theta'(t)|=-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\theta'(t)=\sqrt{2gb\theta(t)}
$$
I tried to solve this differential equation and I concluded that
$$
\theta=\frac{gb}{2(a^2+b^2)}t^2
$$
but I am not sure that this is the right answer. Can anyone verify this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: there was a typo, and I fixed it.

Comment: I think this is more of a physics question than a math question. As to the question itself, the particle moves along the surface of a cylinder. So maybe use cylindrical coordinates would make things easier?

Comment: What happened to the sine and cosine? They can't simplify by $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$, because the coefficients are different.... Perhaps your second term $b\sin(\theta)j$ should be $a\sin(\theta)j$?

Comment: I think $\theta$ should be negative, so the speed would be $\sqrt{2gb|\theta|} = \sqrt{-2gb\theta}$.

Comment: @mr_e_man I believe $z(t)$ is taken from the top, so the distance fallen is always positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you made a typo and the equation of motion actually is

$$ \textbf{r}(t) = a\cos\theta(t)\ \textbf{i} + a\sin\theta(t)\ \textbf{j} + b\theta(t)\ \textbf{k} $$

which is actually the shape of a helix

The initial condition implies $\theta(0) = 0$

The velocity vector is

$$ \textbf{r}'(t) = \big[{-a}\sin\theta(t)\ \textbf{i} + a\cos\theta(t)\ \textbf{j} + b\ \textbf{k}\big]\theta'(t) $$

From the given speed, we have

$$ |\textbf{r}'(t)| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\big|\theta'(t)\big|= \sqrt{2gz(t)} $$

The particle is always falling downwards, so $\theta' \ge 0$ and we can ignore the absolute values

$$ \theta'(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2gb\theta(t)}{a^2+b^2}} $$

Solving the separable equation

$$ \frac{\theta'}{2\sqrt{\theta}} = \sqrt{\frac{gb}{2(a^2+b^2)}} \implies \sqrt{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{gb}{2(a^2+b^2)}}t + c $$

where $\theta(0)=0$ gives $c=0$, thus

$$ \theta(t) = \frac{gb}{2(a^2+b^2)}t^2 $$